# What is a Dirac bi-density?

Tags: distribution-theory, dirac-delta

In https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9210011 on p. 22 the author encounters the Dirac bi-density $\delta(x,x')$ in certain Poisson bracket relations in Hamiltonian mechanics.

He says that $\delta(x,x')$ is a scalar density of weight zero in its first argument and a scalar density of weight one in its second argument. The latter means $f(x)=\int f(x')\delta(x,x')dx'$. But what does the former mean?

[Crossposted to [phys.SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/772704/what-is-a-dirac-bi-density)]

Comment: I'm not sure, but I guess that it just means that $f(x)$ will be a scalar.

Comment: @md2perpe what exactly is the definition of a scalar?

Comment: A scalar is an entity, the value of which is the same in every coordinate system.

Comment: @md2perpe Ah I see. So if $x'\to f(x')$ then $\delta(x,x')\to\delta(x,f(x'))/|f'(x')|$ and if $x\to f(x)$ then $\delta(x,x')\to\delta(f(x),x')$

Comment: Something like that, yes.